# Can i read and write files on the kindle filesystem from a kindle active content app?

Tags: java, kindle, kindle-kdk

Can Kindle Development Kit Applications read and write to  files placed on a kindle by usb?

my program would pretty much do the following

1.a user/supervisor places an xml or json file on the device using usb
2.at start read the file into the program
3.Some User Activities
4.The results of the user activities written to the same file or another file
5.a user/supervisor copies the file off of the device for processing by a backend system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read/write files that are created from the application. Once the directory for your application is created (each application gets its own directory), you can mount the Kindle and then modify those files.